# How to solve jQuery conflicts on IE using jQuery.noConflict()?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins

We have a site that we would like our customers to embed in their websites using an iFrame. Unfortunately, it works in every browser except for the miserable IE 6, 7 and 8.

The problem is that we get:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

on the first mention of $ in our jQuery. We know why this is happening, apparently it is due to conflicts with an existing JS library at our customer's site. However, what we don't know is how to fix it.

This is a Rails 3 application that uses the jQuery 1.4.2. We don't know *where* to put the `jQuery.noConflict()` call. Also, we're confused as to what that would do to the numerous jQuery plugins we are doing. Can anybody offer any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`noConflict()` gives up control of the `$` so other libraries may use it.

I would wrap all your jQuery code with this code.

```
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
```

This will effectively pass the `$` back to your ready function so you may use it like you are expecting to.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `jQuery.noConflict();` as your first JS statement that gets run on the page (after loading your libs).

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery.noConflict();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**

```
$something=jQuery.noConflict();

now $something becomes $,
```

eg :

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j('#anElement').addClass('red');
```

**2**  For Handling plug-ins, using all plug-ins use jQuery in place of $

if any plug-in is using $ than to this

```
//your plugin file
(function(){
$=jQuery;
})();
```